# Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS: tc filter rule hits not shown

Tags: traffic

Have a Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. There is no rule hits stats in the output of tc filter show command:

tc -s -d filter show dev eth0

```
filter parent 1: protocol all pref 1 u32
filter parent 1: protocol all pref 1 u32 fh 800: ht divisor 1
filter parent 1: protocol all pref 1 u32 fh 800::800 order 2048 key ht 800 bkt 0 flowid 1:11
  match 0afc0200/ffffff00 at 16
filter parent 1: protocol all pref 1 u32 fh 800::801 order 2049 key ht 800 bkt 0 flowid 1:11
  match 0afcc900/ffffff00 at 16
filter parent 1: protocol all pref 2 u32
filter parent 1: protocol all pref 2 u32 fh 801: ht divisor 1
filter parent 1: protocol all pref 2 u32 fh 801::800 order 2048 key ht 801 bkt 0 flowid 1:12
  match 00000000/00000000 at 16
filter parent 1: protocol all pref 2 u32 fh 801::801 order 2049 key ht 801 bkt 0 flowid 1:12
```

The same command output at Debian:

```
filter parent 1: protocol all pref 1 u32
filter parent 1: protocol all pref 1 u32 fh 800: ht divisor 1
filter parent 1: protocol all pref 1 u32 fh 800::800 order 2048 key ht 800 bkt 0 flowid 1:11  (rule hit 62382829 success 24954907)
  match 0afc0200/ffffff00 at 16 (success 24954907 )
filter parent 1: protocol all pref 1 u32 fh 800::801 order 2049 key ht 800 bkt 0 flowid 1:11  (rule hit 37427922 success 2200029)
  match 0afcc900/ffffff00 at 16 (success 2200029 )
filter parent 1: protocol all pref 2 u32
filter parent 1: protocol all pref 2 u32 fh 801: ht divisor 1
filter parent 1: protocol all pref 2 u32 fh 801::800 order 2048 key ht 801 bkt 0 flowid 1:12  (rule hit 35227893 success 35227893)
  match 00000000/00000000 at 16 (success 35227893 )
filter parent 1: protocol all pref 2 u32 fh 801::801 order 2049 key ht 801 bkt 0 flowid 1:12  (rule hit 0 success 0)
```

How can I enable such stats?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) What happens if you copy the binary from Debian over the Ubuntu one?  **Backup first!** I'm suspecting a compiler flag different between Deb and Ub...

Comment: Probably, Ubuntu kernel compiled without CONFIG_CLS_U32_PERF=yes flag. So there are no rule hits stats.

Comment: There you go!  So if I were you, I'd answer my own question now...  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo 1 > /sys/module/sch_htb/parameters/htb_rate_est
```

Comment: perhaps you might invest a bit more time in helping the OP understand how this will answer his question....